# Change applied to HTML element style from JS function does not show up

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a short snippet of my code

```js
function checkFields() {
    const nameFormat = /^[a-zA-Z-' -]*$/;

    let fieldPrenom = document.getElementById("prenom");
    let divPrenom = document.getElementById("divPrenom");
    if (!fieldPrenom.value.match(nameFormat)) {
        divPrenom.innerHTML = "<br><p>Only letters please</p>" + divPrenom.innerHTML
        highlightRed(fieldPrenom);
        return false;
    } else return true;
}

function highlightRed (inputBox) {
    inputBox.style.border = "0.2vw solid red";
    console.log("Current border style : " + inputBox.style.border);
}
```

```css
input.default {
    border: 0.1vw solid;
    border-radius: 0.25vw;
    min-width: 30vw;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 0.6vw;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkFields()">
<div class="questions" id="divPrenom">
<input id="prenom" type="text" required class="default">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="default"/>
</form>
```

If you run it, you see that my inputBox does not highlight in red although `Current border style : 0.2vw solid red` is logged in console. So why are the changes not rendered ?

I also tried to not use a function to highlight in red and do it directly in `checkFields` like this :

```js
if (!fieldPrenom.value.match(nameFormat)) {
     divPrenom.innerHTML = "<br><p>Only letters please</p>" + divPrenom.innerHTML
     fieldPrenom.style.border = "0.2vw solid red";
     return false;
    }
```

But here something very weird happens : the inputBox borders turn into red but only if you *fail* two times the validation (eg. enter "123", submit, then do the same thing) again and border should finally become red.

Any help is much appreciated

### Side note

I know that if you try multiple times to validate, the "Only letter please" paragraph will print itself several times but I have this fixed in my code I simply not included in this snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call

```
highlightRed(fieldPrenom);
```

before this statement

```
divPrenom.innerHTML = "<br><p>Only letters please</p>" + divPrenom.innerHTML;
```

because the latter statement recreates the element inside the div and thus *fieldPrenom* in

```
let fieldPrenom = document.getElementById("prenom");
```

isn't assigned to the newly created element.

**Note:** In your regex `/^[a-zA-Z-' -]*$/` you are matching the `-` character twice, so I removed one instance of the character.

**Test below:**

```js
function checkFields() {
  const nameFormat = /^[a-zA-Z' -]*$/;

  let fieldPrenom = document.getElementById("prenom");
  let divPrenom = document.getElementById("divPrenom");
  if (!fieldPrenom.value.match(nameFormat)) {
    highlightRed(fieldPrenom);
    divPrenom.innerHTML = "<br><p>Only letters please</p>" + divPrenom.innerHTML;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function highlightRed(inputBox) {
  inputBox.style.border = "0.2vw solid red";
  console.log("Current border style : " + inputBox.style.border);
}
```

```css
input.default {
  border: 0.1vw solid;
  border-radius: 0.25vw;
  min-width: 30vw;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 0.6vw;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkFields()">
  <div class="questions" id="divPrenom">
    <input id="prenom" type="text" required class="default">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="default" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you set the `.innerHTML` on this line:

```
divPrenom.innerHTML = "<br><p>Only letters please</p>" + divPrenom.innerHTML
```

You wind up recreating the element.

In general, `.innerHTML` should always be avoided when possible as this is one common side-effect and there are also performance and security implications to its use.

There are several other things that you should do differently here so that you can not only avoid that issue, but make your code use modern approaches that avoid pitfalls.

See comments:

```js
// The following should just be set once, not every time the 
// function runs.
const nameFormat = /^[a-zA-Z-' -]*$/;
const fieldPrenom = document.getElementById("prenom");
const divPrenom = document.getElementById("divPrenom");
const form = document.querySelector("form");

// Reference the element that will display any errors:
const error = document.getElementById("error");

// Set up events using the modern standard:
form.addEventListener("submit", checkFields)

// DOM event handlers that are set up with .addEventListener()
// automatically recieve a reference to the event that triggered them.
function checkFields(event) {
    if (!fieldPrenom.value.match(nameFormat)) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Cancel the event!
      
      // Now, we can just write the non-HTML message into the
      // one element where it's needed and don't have to replace
      // any HTML anywhere.
      error.textContent = "Only letters please";   
      highlightRed(fieldPrenom);
    }
}

function highlightRed (inputBox) {
  // Just add a class to override the border portion of the one already added:
  inputBox.classList.add("red");
  // .getComputedStyle() gets the style no matter how it was set
  console.log("Current border style : " + getComputedStyle(inputBox).border);
}
```

```css
/* Keep basic class selectors as non-specific as possible
   so you can override them easily when needed. */

.default {
    border: 0.1vw solid;
    border-radius: 0.25vw;
    min-width: 30vw;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 0.6vw;
}


/* Use classes over inline styles whenever possible.
   This reduces code redundancy and makes the code
   easier to read and write. */
.red {border: 0.2vw solid red; }
```

```html
<!-- Don't use inline event attributes to set up events.
     Set up events separately, in JavaScript. -->
<form>
  <div class="questions" id="divPrenom">
    <!-- We will avoid having to use .innerHTML in the first place
         by just having a placeholder element waiting that we can
         write any messages (not HTML) into.-->
    <p id="error"></p>
    <input id="prenom" type="text" required class="default">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="default">
</form>
```

Comment: First thank you for your answer. I have a question about this line `inputBox.classList.add("red");` When you run the classList.add(class), does it "add" the new class to the element to the other existing classes or does this function *removes* all classes from the element and then set the new class ? (so in the second case, it would be more a "replace all" function). I hope my question is understandable :/

Comment: @ScarySneer You're welcome. The short answer is that it applies the instructions in the `red` class to that one element that you are calling `.classList.add()` on. It does not affect any other elements. Because the instructions in the `red` class conflict with the `border` portion of the already applied `default` class, only that aspect of the styling is overridden.

Comment: @ScarySneer So, to be clear, when you apply a class to an element, you are "adding" its instructions to the styling of just that element. If the new instructions don't conflict with the styling that's already applied, the element winds up with a combination of both styles. If the new class being added has a conflict with some aspect of the already applied style, then just that aspect is overridden with the instructions in the new class being applied. This process is literally the "cascade" effect in the name Cascading Style Sheets.